# Grails on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with strange Error ... /3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict

Tags: java, ubuntu, grails, gradle

I am unable to run any Grails application in the Ubuntu OS. I could not identify any issue with my IDE, JAVA, Grails installation. I tried all the grails version -3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.5. I am attaching all the stacktrace.

Here are OS, JVM info and full stacktrace :

```
inviit-07@inviit07:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

inviit-07@inviit07:~$ more /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"

Grails Version: 3.1.5
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_73

~/development/untitled33$ grails clean --stacktrace --verbose

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'untitled33'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for org.grails:grails-dependencies:3.1.5
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-dependencies/3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-dependencies/3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.786 secs
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-dependencies/3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-dependencies/3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.processResponse(HttpClientHelper.java:123)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHead(HttpClientHelper.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getMetaData(HttpResourceAccessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.getMetaData(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResourceMetaData(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.staticResourceExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.artifactExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findOptionalArtifacts(ExternalResourceResolver.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver$MavenRemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveConfigurationArtifacts(MavenResolver.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$AbstractRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(ExternalResourceResolver.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(ExternalResourceResolver.java:420)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$4.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:242)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveModuleArtifacts(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveModuleArtifacts(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ArtifactResolverChain.resolveModuleArtifacts(ComponentResolversChain.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$2.execute(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$2.execute(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver$4.run(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver.executeInContext(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ContextualArtifactResolver.resolveModuleArtifacts(ContextualArtifactResolver.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveModuleArtifacts(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.doResolve(ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.getArtifacts(ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.visitEdge(ResolvedArtifactsGraphVisitor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.CompositeDependencyGraphVisitor.visitEdge(CompositeDependencyGraphVisitor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.assembleResult(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:367)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:342)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:335)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:661)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.GrailsGradlePlugin$_createPathingJarTask_closure18$_closure34.doCall(GrailsGradlePlugin.groovy:477)
    at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.GrailsGradlePlugin$_createPathingJarTask_closure18.doCall(GrailsGradlePlugin.groovy:476)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:488)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated$create.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.GrailsGradlePlugin.createPathingJarTask(GrailsGradlePlugin.groovy:471)
    at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.GrailsGradlePlugin$_configurePathingJar_closure19.doCall(GrailsGradlePlugin.groovy:509)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:496)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:87)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:87)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-dependencies/3.1.5/grails-dependencies-3.1.5.jar'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
```

Answer (score 1):

I reported the issue on the bug tracker for Grails (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9879). The issue is most probably caused by a problem with the Grails Maven serve, because it still worked on friday and works on systems where the basic dependencies where already loaded by earlier runs. The issue persists over several OS and versions of Grails.